# onProviderDisabled - need gps in battery saving mode

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

onProviderDisabled is telling me the gps is disabled. I want to be able to get the lat and lon in the wifi gps mode as well as the full gps mode.

I am using this code to start up

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
        3000,   
        1, this);
```

It all works with the full GPS on but I need to be able to get the lat and lon in either mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request updates from more than one provider. Add the following line:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager. NETWORK_PROVIDER, 3000, 1, this);
```

The same callback methods, i.e. `onLocationChanged()`, `onProviderDisabled()`, etc.,  will be used to pass the updates from both providers. If you need to know which provider is passing the update, you can use the `Location.getProvider()` method in `onLocationChanged()`, and the `String provider` parameter passed in the others.

Comment: Thank you! I sure appreciate the help!

Comment: How about when using `FusedLocationProviderClient`? The `requestLocationUpdates` has only `LocationRequest`, `LocationCallback`, and `Looper` as parameters.

Comment: @Dr.jacky I'm not sure what you're asking, but I haven't done anything with location tracking in years, and I never did do anything with the fused location provider. Sorry.